# How to insert a list of values as an IN(list) criterion in a query?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Consider a table like the following

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 someVal INTEGER
);
```

filled with some data (just to not feel like querying an empty table) and a query as follows

```
SELECT tbl1.ID, tbl1.someVal
FROM tbl1
WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([TempVar]![t1]));
```

The TempVars collection has been filled with the contents

```
TempVars.Add "t1", 1
TempVars.Add "t2", "2"
TempVars.Add "t3", "2,3"
```

via the immediate window.

Now when viewing the query results for different `WHERE` clauses the following scenarios work (meaning they display the expected results):

- Querying for `WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([TempVar]![t1]))` returns the entry with `id = 1`
- Querying for `WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([TempVar]![t2]))` returns the entry with `id = 2`

So far, everything as expected. But for `WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([TempVar]![t3]))` the query results are empty. **Why?**
(When I execute `?TempVars("t3")` it returns `2,3` - when I then copy/paste that line into the query so it reads `WHERE (tbl1.ID In (2,3))` it returns the entries 2 and 3...)

---

Things to consider:

- I'm using the German version of Access 2013, which means that your name for the `TempVars` collection might differ (for me, in the VBE it's called `TempVars`, while the query design only allows access via `[TempVar]`).
- Also when manually entering lists into the criterion field in query design mode, I need to separate them with a semicolon, whereas in SQL mode I'm required to use a comma. Stupid language differences. (Whether I define `TempVars("t3")` with a semicolon or comma doesn't change anything about the zero results, however...)
- My research suggests that the very method presented above *should* work, so I assume I either implemented it wrong or there is something else at play.
- My approach isn't necessarily tied to the usage of `TempVars`. When experimenting with the values of textbox and label controls on forms, I experienced the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Why* is very easy to answer. If `TempVars("t3")` contains a string `"2, 3"`, it's only going to match entries where your ID is a string equal to `"2, 3"`. You can't dynamically build IN criteria the way you're doing it, since the `,` can't be stored in a variable, it has to be present in the SQL.

To fix this, you can use a user-defined function to do the `IN` check for you. There aren't other solid workarounds as long as you're not dynamically changing your SQL.

Sample UDF:

```vb
Public Function SplitIn(commaseparatedlist As String, compare As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim strInArr() As String
    strInArr = Split(commaseparatedlist, ",")
    Dim arrItem As Variant
    For Each arrItem In strInArr
        If arrItem = CStr(Nz(compare, "")) Then
            SplitIn = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next arrItem
    SplitIn = False
End Function
```

Usage:

```sql
WHERE SplitIn([TempVar]![t3], tbl1.ID)
```

Comment: So there is a technical difference between `WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([var1], [var2]))` and `WHERE (tbl1.ID In ([var3]))` with `var3 = var1 & "," & var2`? Who would have thought. I guess I need to look into dynamically modifying my query then.

Comment: Yes, there is, and it's a pretty common obstacle, since in your first example, you have 2 constants, and you're comparing your ID to both of them, and in your second, you have only one constant. You can't dynamically add constants without dynamically changing your SQL. You can, however, initialize x constants, use them all in the SQL, and set them to `False` or something that doesn't occur if they're unused.

Comment: To reiterate on that: The problem then is not my understanding of how to formulate my data but rather Access' SQL interpreter?

Comment: Well, I'd say it's more just the way the SQL IN criterium works. If you pass it one variable, it's only going to see one variable, regardless of the amount of comma's inside it. And that's not a bug, and usual for other SQL dialects too.

Comment: I see, thanks. Having a constant for every option quickly gets unwieldy, so that's a clear case in favor of dynamically updating the SQL. The funny thing is that I spent hours researching and experimenting on the issue and never even once was my specific problem mentioned. (That or I need to see my optician...) ;)

Comment: I just saw your edit: Awesome work! I have not been using UDFs so far, so thanks for introducing me to them. :) When testing your code, I realized there's a type conversion missing - in my example it's comparing `"2" = 2` which is `false`. So I guess the best approach would be to have `str$(compare)`, as the other side of the comparison is passed in as string anyway. Also I'm accepting your answer as I can't imagine someone else having *a better* answer to my question. Cheers!

Comment: Well, since they're both variants, and `"1"=1` results in `True` in VBA, there's no real need, but it doesn't hurt too. Glad to help

Comment: My VBA seems to disagree. `arrItem` has the type `Variant/String` whereas `compare` comes as `Variant/Long`. The comparison `arrItem = compare` always results in `False` for me. I needed to compare `arrItem = CStr(compare)` to get a `True`.

Comment: Ah, odd, I've adjusted the function in the answer